# Subtracting Elements of List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I've a list of integers that I want to subtract from each other in consecutive order. I want to be able to use the code for any size list of integers, even if I don't know the number of integers.

What I've so far:

```
a = [10, 9, 8]  # Example list with 3 integers
sub = 0
for i, n in enumerate(a):
    sub = a[i] - a[i+1]
print(sub)
```

My expected answer is -7 because:

10 - 9 = 1

Then 1 - 8 = -7

10 and 9 are the first and second element of the list `a`, respectively. I subtract them to get 1. I then take 1 and deduct 8 -- the third element of the list -- from it to get -7.

Instead, I get an error that the list index is out of range. I know why I'm getting this: because when `i` hits 2, `i+1` becomes 3, and there is no `a[3]` element in the list.

Yet for something so simple, I can't seem to figure out how to obtain consecutive indices like this, especially for a list where I wouldn't know the number of elements.

How can I fix this? Should I just use a `try-except` clause and `break` out of the loop when I get the `IndexError`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your expected output of -7, you need to be subtracting from the running difference prior to the element you're currently on, rather than `a[i] - a[i+1]`.

In terms of the index issue, you can resolve it by adding in a logical check to make sure that you have remaining elements in the array by bounding the end point to be `len(a) - 1`

```
a = [10, 9, 8]  # Example list with 3 integers
sub = a[0]
for i, n in enumerate(a):
    if i < (len(a) - 1):
        sub = sub - a[i + 1]
print(sub)
```

Comment: Yea I realized after I posted that my logic was wrong; I should've kept the *running* difference, not the *consecutive* difference. Your line with the `if` statement is also what I was searching for! Thanks!

Comment: Note: Testing `i < len(a) - 1` on every loop is optimizing for the uncommon case at the expense of the common case. Changing the loop to `for x in a[1:]: sub -= x` or `for i in range(1, len(a)): sub -= a[i]`, or even just wrapping the loop in `try/except IndexError: pass` would achieve the same effect (operating on all values except the first) with much lower overhead (Python level math, `len` checks, and indexing all have higher overhead than you might expect).

Answer (score 4):

Simpler and faster solution than explicit loops or `reduce`: Realizing that `a - b - c - ... - n` is equivalent to `a - (b + c + ... + n)`, so you can use the `sum` function (which is optimized at the C layer for sums that fit in a C `long`, only falling back to more expensive Python level `int`s if it overflows a C `long`).

```
a = [10, 9, 8]  # Example list with 3 integers
sub = a[0] - sum(a[1:])
print(sub)
```

Note: This makes a shallow copy of most of `a`, and requires a sequence type (to support indexing/slicing), not any iterable. You can fix both issues with the slightly longer code:

```
a = [10, 9, 8]  # Example list with 3 integers
aiter = iter(a)  # Make iterator from any iterable
sub = next(aiter) - sum(aiter)  # Pull first item from iterator, then pass rest to sum
print(sub)
```

This will be ever-so-slightly slower for small input `list`s (fixed overhead from `iter`/`next` being slightly greater than fixed overhead of indexing/slicing, though slicing has growing overhead of copy that `iter`/`next` lacks), but the savings on longer inputs would more than make up for it.

Comment: I see your logic about `a - (b + c + ... + n)`, and that's definitely something I didn't consider. I did know about `sum()`, but wanted to avoid using that because I wanted to practice a bit with explicit iteration and loops (since I'm trying to learn C++, which I don't think has `sum()`).

I don't fully understand your point about "shallow copy of most of `a`" though. Do you mean that a new `list` object is created and stored in memory when I use `sum()`, and that's what you were trying to avoice with `iter()`?

Comment: @WaterGuy: It's not the `sum` itself, it's the slice operation on `a`; `a[1:]` makes a new `list` containing all but the first element of `a`. As for "trying to learn C++", doing so in Python isn't exactly a useful start; different languages have different strengths and features, and trying to learn C++ via a language with very limited similarities won't get you very far. As for C++ and `sum`, [it's spelled `std::reduce` in C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce) (the default reduction function is addition, making it a `sum` function). :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) along with [`operator.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.sub)

```
from operator import sub
from functools import reduce

a = [10, 9, 8]

reduce(sub, a)
# -7
```

This is roughly equivalent to

```
a = [10, 9, 8]

accumulator = a[0]
for x in a[1:]:
    accumulator -= x

print(accumulator)
# -7
```

Comment: Very concise! I'd heard of `reduce()` but never used it before! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import reduce
num=[100,20,30,12,15,10]
print(reduce(lambda x,y:x-y,num))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just after the total result for the entire list (i.e. `[10,9,8]` results in an answer of `-7` as opposed to a result of `[10, 1, -7]`) then then you simply need to subtract the sum of all the values after the first item. The order of subtraction does not matter.

```py
import numpy as np
a = [10, 9, 8]
sub = a[0] - np.sum(a[1:])
```

If you want the cumulative result (i.e. result of `[10, 1, -7]`) then use the `cumsum` function:

```py
sub = np.append(a[0], a[0] - np.cumsum(a[1:]))
```